# Why does Chrome closes connection when REST API returns a large response?

Tags: java, google-chrome, networking, download

I use this REST API

```
@GET
@Path("/get-file")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8")
public void getFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, 
        @QueryParam("filePath") String filePath, @QueryParam("fileName") String fileName) throws IOException {fileName);
    File fileToDownload = new File(filePath);
    if (fileToDownload.exists()) {
        java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(fileToDownload.toURI());
        
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        
        try {
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(Files.size(path)));
            
            Files.copy(path, response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }
    } else {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

to download files generated from the server. It all works fine if the file i'm trying to get is less than 50GB (more or less), but when I try to download a 50GB while using Chrome, I get a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` exception. This doesn't happen in Firefox, and I can get the file as usual.

This is what I see in the Chrome Network Tab:

[image: Chrome Network Tab]

Downloading the file is the only operation I do and it the fails immediately.
If I omit the `CONTENT_LENGTH` header from the response, the size of the response reaches 48GB~ and then I get the same error.

Does anyone have any clue about this? On server side I use Java 7 (I tried with Java 8 too) and on client side I use AngularJS v1.5.11. I use ApacheTomcat to deploy my application. Let me know if you need more info about the problem.